# no space between my string when using Text.rich() in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using the Text.rich() in my flutter app.
Below is the snippet of my Text.rich():

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text.rich(
      TextSpan(
        children: <TextSpan>[
          TextSpan(
            text: "Hello ",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          TextSpan(
            text: "to",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          TextSpan(
            text: "flutter",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

I am getting my output as:
**Hello toflutter**

I am new to flutter and just wanted to know why there is no space between 'to' and 'flutter' letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you forgot the space in to `"to "`, check how Hello as a space at the end. Also Text.rich and TextSpan is more useful when you want to use different styles in the same text, but you're using the same, I would recommend just using a Text widget with a style in this case

```
Text('Hello to flutter', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
```

Comment: Oh Ok, didn't see the space. thanx